# Is there a way to match a string in a file and print/append the contents of another file (single line) on the next line after string match

Tags: awk

I am trying to match a string in a file and print/append the contents of another file after the string match

I have file "addthis" containing single line `pleaseaddme`:

```
pleaseaddme
```

and I have a second file "tothis" containing two lines [one] and [two] like so:

```
[one]

[two]
```

I have tried combinations resulting in the following which is close to my desired result:

```
awk '/\[one\]/ { printf $0; getline < "addthis" }1' tothis
```

Result:

```
[one]please add me

[two]
```

**I would like** "please add me" to be added to a new line after [one]
like so:

```
[one]
please add me
[two]
```

Also this is only printing to the screen and not into the file "tothis"

Have tried numerous variations this as close as I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with:

```
>> awk '/\[one\]/ {getline s < "addthis"; $0=$0 "\n" s;} /[^\s]+/{print}' tothis
[one]
pleaseaddme
[two]
```

If you want to replace in your file you must add the `-i inplace`:

```
>> awk -i inplace '/\[one\]/ {getline s < "addthis"; $0=$0 "\n" s;} /[^\s]+/{print}' tothis
>> cat tothis
[one]
pleaseaddme
[two]
```

If you couldn't use `-i inplace`, you should achieve the same with:

```
>> awk '/\[one\]/ {getline s < "addthis"; $0=$0 "\n" s;} /[^\s]+/{print}' tothis > fckmack && mv fckmack tothis
```

Comment: >> awk '/\[one\]/ {getline s < "addthis"; $0=$0 "\n" s;} /[^\s]+/{print}' tothis gets the correct output but does not save it into the "tothis" file  with the -i inplace i get error      awk: unknown option -i ignored

awk: can't open file /\[one\]/ {getline s < "addthis"; $0=$0 "\n" s;} /[^\s]+/{print}
 source line number 1

Comment: Yep, the second one does. I separate them.

Comment: @whyfoo are u using GNU-awk?

Comment: testing on mac awk version is awk version 20070501

Comment: >> awk '/\[one\]/ {getline s < "addthis"; $0=$0 "\n" s;} /[^\s]+/{print}' tothis ...works as desired but does not save to file

Comment: If you find this useful, consider to accept this answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/\[one\]/ {getline var< "addthis"; $0 = $0 ORS var }1' tothis
#=> [one]
#=> pleaseaddme
#=> [two]
```

First thing you should escape `[` and `]`.
And then read file to a variable, and "append" it to current line.

Another way to do it could be:

```
awk '/\[one\]/ {print; getline var< "addthis"; print var; next }1' tothis
```

As of your own attempt, actually change `printf` to `print` will work:

```
awk '/\[one\]/ { print $0; getline < "addthis" }1' tothis
#=> [one]
#=> pleaseaddme
#=> [two]
```

Because `printf` won't print `ORS` but `print` will.
However on this account, `$0` is superfluous as print without parameter will print `$0` by default.

As for change in place, you can still redirect to a temp file and replace file later.

Comment: I try the same, but I get this output, with the first command:
```[one]
pleaseaddme

[two]```, (two `newline` after `pleaseaddme`)

Comment: First one: `awk '/\[one\]/ {getline var< "addthis"; $0 = $0 ORS var }1' tothis`

Comment: GNU-awk, Linux-

Comment: was thinking that might be issue - testing on macos 10.14 seems no -i option

Comment: @FcknGioconda   Could you check the output of `awk --version` ? Also please check the content of `addthis` and `tothis` file. In OP's question, there were actually two `newline` after `[one]`.

Comment: OP's file has two newlines after `[one]`.

Comment: @FcknGioconda  Just tried on CentOS7 GNU Awk 4.0.2, don't have the problem you described. The `tothis` file I created only have `[one]` and `[two]` two lines.

Comment: @FcknGioconda  No, that's just a editing problem I guess. He did said it has two lines `[one]` and `[two]`  above.

Comment: @whyfoo You can `brew install gawk` and start using `gawk` next time.

Answer (score 0):

Given my awk version on mac this works

> > awk '/[one]/ {getline s < "addthis"; $0=$0 "\n" s;} /[^\s]+/{print}' tothis > fckmack && mv fckmack tothis